# What is the soft and the hard thresholding operator?

Tags: regression, terminology, threshold

I'm trying to understand in simple words what the soft and hard thresholding operators are **and what they do**?

I looked some examples on the internet but I can't find anything simple.

Any suggestion of what I could read to understand it ?